# MSA2312i shows duplicate enclosures?

Tags: storage, hp, storage-area-network

I just installed a redundant controller in my MSA70. This is in use with our old MSA2312i SAN.

Now I'm seeing two entries for 'Enclosure 3' (the associated MSA70 disk shelf) in the UI. It appears that both the modules are reporting as controller A, versus the newly added controller showing as B as it usually would.

What should I look at for an underlying cause here? I've already updated the firmware. 
[image: Multiple Enclosure 3s]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrading the firmware to 2.18 I tried redetecting via the UI without impact.

Unplugging and reseating the module did it though.

It did take about an extra 15 minutes.. Apparently for syncing the configuration.

Comment: When you run into roadblocks, check [firmware revisions and release notes](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6195/13325).

Comment: @ewwhite. Indeed. :) I actually had that on meta a couple days after you posted. The odd thing was that I needed to run the firmware installer twice for the same version. I have no idea why.